# Keep getting Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ...\wp-includes\post.php on line 4153 when generating woocommerce coupon

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm getting this error, that I can't get rid of.
Here is my code:

```php
function generate_coupon($coupon_name){
  global $post;
  $coupon_code = $coupon_name; // Code
  $amount = '10'; // Amount
  $discount_type = 'percent'; // Type: fixed_cart, percent, fixed_product, percent_product

  $coupon = array(
    'post_title' => $coupon_code,
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_type'     => 'shop_coupon'
  );

  $new_coupon_id = wp_insert_post( $coupon );

  // Add meta
  update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'discount_type', $discount_type );
  update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'coupon_amount', $amount );
  update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'individual_use', 'no' );
  update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'product_ids', '' );
  update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'exclude_product_ids', '' );
  update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'usage_limit', '' );
  update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'expiry_date', '' );
  update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'apply_before_tax', 'yes' );
  update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'free_shipping', 'no' );

}
generate_coupon('00112233');
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: your code works well with last versions of WordPress and WooCommerce. maybe another plugin is creating this error.

Comment: Just to make sure we're looking at the same line 4153, which version of the WordPress do you have? If it's 5.1.x or 5.2.x then I make [line 4153 `$feeds = $wp_rewrite->feeds;`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.2.3/wp-includes/post.php#L4153) so the problem is that the `$wp_rewrite` global isn't available in [wp_unique_post_slug](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_unique_post_slug/). Does that sound plausible?

Comment: Where is this code? How are you calling it? Is it potentially in an environment where WP_Rewrite hasn't been initialised?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of wordpress and woocommerce and still getting that error. I have tried disabling plugins, that didn't work, however, what worked is placing this code in functions.php, but I can't have that.

Comment: This code is with in a custom plugin